# Movesense - Sensor disconnects after 35 seconds

Tags: android, movesense

We have developed an application with Movesense. The application connects and subscribes to the Accelerometers. 
It is running for 35 seconds and receives data from the sensor. 
Each time after 35 seconds the sensor stops sending data (Not sending onNotification(String data)) and after a few more seconds disconnects. Few more seconds later it reconnects and continues to send data.
This totally ruins the user experience and the ability to work with Movesense.
We have tried 4 different Movesense sensors. The problem exists in all.
Also we updated firmware to all our sensors, but the problem did not go away.
In the Device Documentation in the file "Changes.md" we found the following 2 lines:

"Known Bugs:"
"HR stops sending data after Acc/Magn/Gyro subscription"

Reading trough most of the device-lib documentation, and the issues in Stuck-overflow (i.e. here) we were not able to find any further documentation about this issue.
We have a few obvious questions:
1. Is what we see is the "Known Bug"?
2. If yes, is there any further documentation on it?
3. If yes, is there a known workaround for it?
4. If no, what would you recommend to do?

Thanks,
Eric.

**Update:** After testing with mobile devices with API 23 or higher the problem disappeared. The original mobile device was API 22. Also, since we don't have another device with API 22 or lower, we cannot rule-out that the API 22 device has some issue in its Bluetooth which may not be related to the API.
  I am leaving this question unanswered since we would still like to ask how or where to find more details about the known bug “HR stops sending data after Acc/Magn/Gyro subscription” described by this sentence in the Movesense Device Lib documentation.

Thanks,
Eric.

Comment: Note the update in the description.

Comment: It looks like a bug but not connected with HR. I'm not sure if the bug is in the firmware part or in the mobile part. Do you have jig? And logs from the Movesense?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have either a jig or logs from the Movesense. As I described above: in the devices that we have-  the problem does not appear in API 23 or higher. Perhaps that is intentional? Perhaps API 22 or lower is not supported?

Comment: Another thing to consider: are you using the hr_wakeup_app or similar on sensor that switches off after 1 minute if not connected? If your API22 phone is BLE <= 4.1, the connect may be so slow that the 1 minute is up before it is completed.